# Select two rows, using data from one row

Tags: mysql

Here's my db structure:

```
id | title | parent_title
```

Sometimes a row will have a parent_title and sometimes it won't.

When it does have a parent title, is it possible to also get it's parent's title out of the database in the same query.

So, for example:

```
id | title | parent_title
1  | BMW   | 
2  | Ford  |
3  | KA    | Ford
```

So I select id and title where id = 3. How can I also get the parents title out (if parents id exists)?

I know the db set up isn't ideal, but i'm unable to change an old system.

Comment: parent_id'? Nowhere in the information you supply, is there a 'parent_id' column. Please edit your question to include the actual table definitions with the column definitions you are using. Please include the SQL Query that produces the result you give in your question. I assume that the 'parent_title' column came from a separate table of 'Car Manufacturers' with 'Titles'.

Comment: Nope, its a typo, should be parent title, sorry.

Comment: No problem, it happens :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left join, if it has no parent it will return 0

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.title, IFNULL(t2.id,0) AS p_id
FROM mytable t1 
LEFT JOIN mytable t2
ON parent_title = t2.title
```

Comment: Thanks, but I will still need to return the row if parent title is null.

Comment: what is desried result are you looking at from this query, please let me know